# For a Partition $P_n =\{0,1/n,2/n,...,1\}$ show $\inf U(f) = \inf\{U(f,P_n): n \geq 1\}$

Tags: integration

Problem is as follows:

Let $f$ be a bounded function on $[0,1]$. Let $P_n$ be a partition of $[0,1]$ such that $P_n = \left(0,\frac{1}{n},\frac{2}{n},\dots,1\right)$. Finally, we define $\alpha=\inf\{U(f,P_n):n\geq1\}$, where $U(f,P)$ is the upper Darboux sum of $f$ with partition $P$.

Show that $ \alpha = U_f $, with $U_f$ being the upper Darboux integral of $f$, i.e. $U_f = \inf\left\{U(f,P):P\mbox{ is a partition of }[0,1]\right\}$.

We are given the hint, which we showed in class, that for every partition $P$,

$$U(f,P\cup \{s \})-(M_f-m_f) \delta (P) \geq U(f,P)$$ where $s \in [0,1]$, $M_f=\max(f)$ on [0,1] (and correspondingly $m_f$) and $\delta(P)$ is the norm of P.

I was thinking of using a theorem about the upper integral $\bar I=\lim_{\delta(p) \rightarrow0}U(f,P)$, but I can't get it to take me home...

Thanks

Comment: It would be great if you could provide information on the undefined symboles you used. Who, not reading the same book/lecture as you, should know for sure what $U, U_f, P, M_f,m_f,\delta,\dots$ are? I can only guess that it's about oscillations but and Riemann sums.

Comment: You're right, I edited my post. Thank you